# How to convert String to CFMutableString?

Tags: ios, swift, string

The question is very simple. Just how to convert swift String to CFMutableString. I only found [How to convert a swift String to CFString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090322/how-to-convert-a-swift-string-to-cfstring). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show the code what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most immutable classes in Cocoa has a `mutableCopy()` method to return a mutable clone of itself. `NSString.mutableCopy()` returns an `NSMutableString`. `NSData.mutableCopy()` returns an `NSMutableData`, etc.

You can then bridge from Cocoa (`NS*`) to Foundation (`CF*`) class:

```
let str = "Hello world"
let cfString = (str as NSString).mutableCopy() as! CFMutableString
```

Answer (score 2):

as `CFMutableString` is toll-free bridged from `NSMutableString`, you can just create `NSMutableString` from your String then cast it to `CFMutableString`:

```
let str: String = "test 123"
let cfmStr = NSMutableString(string: str) as CFMutableString
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the test string `let str: String = "test 123"`

For **`CFMutableString`** do:

```
(str as! CFMutableString)
```

For **`CFString`** you can do:

```
let cfStr: CFString = str
```

or

```
(str as CFString)
```

since the cast always succeeds.