# Bridging to/from CoreFoundation on Linux

Tags: linux, swift, foundation, core-foundation, toll-free-bridging

I'm trying to compile some code on Linux that uses both CoreFoundation and Foundation, but Linux doesn't implement bridging in the same way macOS and iOS do.

Bridging between Objective-C and Swift works:

```
import Foundation
import CoreFoundation
import Glibc

func wantsNSString(_ string: NSString) {
        print(string)
}

let string = "Hello, world!"
wantsNSString(string._bridgeToObjectiveC())
```

But I can't figure out how to bridge to CoreFoundation.  I can't just pass an `NSString` to a function that wants a `CFString`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreFoundation
import Glibc

func wantsCFString(_ string: CFString) {
        print(string)
}

let string = "Hello, world!"
wantsCFString(string._bridgeToObjectiveC()) //error: cannot convert value of type 'String._ObjectType' (aka 'NSString') to expected argument type 'CFString'
```

I can't just cast it like on macOS:

```
import Foundation
import CoreFoundation
import Glibc

func wantsCFString(_ string: CFString) {
        print(string)
}

let string = "Hello, world!"
wantsCFString(string._bridgeToObjectiveC() as CFString)
//error: 'String._ObjectType' (aka 'NSString') is not convertible to 'CFString'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
```

Using `as!` like the error message suggests compiles but results in a crash at runtime (`Illegal instruction`), and `as?` produces the error:

```
error: conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'CFString' will always succeed
```

[`Bridging.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Bridging.swift) has protocols for converting between NS and CF types, and many types have initializers and properties, but those are all `internal` or `private`.  I *could* just use `CFStringCreateWithCString`, but this needs to work with other class pairs like `InputStream` and `CFReadStream`.

Am I missing something here, or is there really no way to convert between Foundation and CoreFoundation types on Linux?

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24900185/603977 Ugly double cast. Don't know about Linux, though. The big "gotcha" with Swift on Linux is that the ObjC runtime isn't there.

Comment: @JoshCaswell No; bridging between Swift and Foundation [isn't done automatically by the compiler yet](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Issues.md), which is why I have to use  the temporary `_bridgeToObjectiveC` method, and I tried casting from `NSString` to `CFString` in my third example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I can `unsafeBitCast` `NSString` to/from `CFString`:

```
import Foundation
import CoreFoundation
import Glibc

func wantsCFString(_ string: CFString) {
        print(string)
}

let string = "Hello, world!"
wantsCFString(unsafeBitCast(string._bridgeToObjectiveC(), to: CFString.self)
//prints "Hello, world!"
```

This makes sense, since CoreFoundation and Foundation types were designed to have the same memory layout -- that's why toll-free bridging works.  I'm somewhat surprised that it works with the Swift implementation of Foundation though.